# Type erasure and allocators: what's the expected behavior?

Tags: c++, templates, type-erasure, allocator

I asked the same on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but they kindly noted that this question is better suited to SO.

Consider the following code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<memory>

template<typename T>
struct S final {
    struct B {
        virtual void push_back(T&& v) = 0;
        virtual ~B() { }
    };

    template<class Allocator>
    struct D final: public B {
        D(Allocator alloc): vec{alloc} { }
        void push_back(T&& v) override { vec.push_back(v); }
        std::vector<T, Allocator> vec;
    };

    S(): S{std::allocator<T>{}} { } 

    template<class Allocator>
    S(Allocator alloc): ptr{new D<Allocator>{alloc}} { }

    ~S() { delete ptr; }

    void push_back(T&& v) { ptr->push_back(std::move(v)); }

    B* ptr;
};

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    S<int> s1{};
    S<double> s2{std::allocator<double>{}}; 
    s1.push_back(42);
    s2.push_back(x);
}
```

It's a minimal example for the purpose of the question.
The idea is to *type-erase* something that accepts a custom allocator (in this case, a `std::vector`), so as to bend the definition of the container (that has the type of the allocator as part of its type) to something similar to the one of `std::function` (that has not the type of the allocator as part of its type, but still accepts an allocator during the construction).

The code above compiles, but I have doubts about the fact that this class works as it is expected to do.
In other terms, whenever an user of the class provides its own allocator, it is used as an argument for the new `std::vector`, the type of which is erased, but it is not used to allocate the instance of `D` pointed to by `ptr`.

Is this a *valid/logical* design, or the allocator should be used consistently for each allocation?
I mean, is that something that can be found also in the STL or some other major library, or it's something that doesn't make much sense?

Comment: "Is that something that can be found in the STL or some other major library, or is it something that doesn't make much sense" - these options aren't complementary. It can make sense even if the STL doesn't use it. FWIW, your code looks fine (to me).

Comment: Absolutely. More a problem of language, I mean what you got. Sorry. My concern is about the fact that the class forwards the allocator to the internal structure, but it doesn't use the it to allocate that struct (see the call to new). I'm not sure that's what an user usually expects, maybe it would make much sense to use it also for that allocation. Anyway, nice to know that someone finds the approach meaningful!! :-)

Comment: [OT]: your `push_back` should use `std::move` (`std::forward<T>` is equivalent to `std::move` in your case, `vec.push_back(v);` still does the copy). (and so `void S::push_back(T&& v)` expect a rvalue reference, (so changing type of `x` from `int` to `double` would make your code not compile)).

Comment: If you cater to heavy users of custom allocators, don't use bare `new` (obviously).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, you are right, it's a copy-and-paste, cut and reduce from the real code, sorry. I'm fixing the example, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no right answer, the design is reasonable, but it would also be reasonable to use the user-supplied allocator for the creation of the derived object. To do that you'd need to do the destruction and deallocation in the type-erased context, so the allocator can be used:

```
template<typename T>
struct S final {
    struct B {
        // ...
        virtual void destroy() = 0;
    protected:
        virtual ~B() { }
    };

    template<class Allocator>
    struct D final: public B {
        // ...
        void destroy() override {
            using A2 = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::rebind_alloc<D>;
            A2 a{vec.get_allocator()};
            this->~D();
            a2.deallocate(this, 1);
        }
    };

    S(): S{std::allocator<T>{}} { } 

    template<class Allocator>
      S(Allocator alloc): ptr{nullptr} {
          using DA = D<Allocator>;
          using AT = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>;
          static_assert(std::is_same<typename AT::pointer, typename AT::value_type*>::value, "Allocator doesn't use fancy pointers");

          using A2 = AT::rebind_alloc<DA>;
          A2 a2{alloc};
          auto p = a2.allocate(1);
          try {
              ptr = ::new((void*)p) DA{alloc};
          } catch (...) {
              a2.deallocate(p);
              throw;
          }
      }

    ~S() { ptr->destroy(); }

    // ...
};
```

(This code asserts that `Allocator::pointer` is `Allocator::value_type*`, to support allocators where that's not true you would need to use `pointer_traits` to convert between pointer types, which is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: The first version of that class was using `shared_ptr` internally, so an `allocate_shared` after a `rebind` was enough. Anyway, I migrated everything to the `unique_ptr` and found that not using the `allocator` to allocate the internal structure made much sense, but I was not sure about this and that's why I asked. Nice to hear from you (that are far more skilled than me) that *there's no right answer, the design is reasonable*. Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a valid design IF:

You want the memory allocation strategy to be user-defined, but want the interface to the class to be polymorphic. This would be reasonable if for example, some of your objects were being generated by a messaging protocol. In any one message, there may be many objects which could all reasonably be allocated from the same memory chunk (owned by the message) for performance reasons.

However:

1. Obviously you'll want to either implement ptr in terms of a smart pointer, or very carefully write all your copy/move constructors/operators.
2. You'll need to manage very carefully the copying (and certainly moving!) of objects from one type-erased container to another. It might well be invalid to allow a move of an object allocated with allocator A into a container managed by allocator B, for example. This kind of thing becomes difficult to reason about very quickly. There will need to be runtime check, perhaps throw a `std::logic_error` if this is violated (or maybe degrade to a copy?), and so on.

Comment: Moving objects between containers _shouldn't_ be a problem. How an object was allocated doesn't usually affect its state, and doesn't mean you can't copy/move it to create another object in memory allocated differently. e.g. I can create an object with `new` then push it into a container using some custom allocator. That's fundamentally the same as what you say needs great care here.

Comment: I confirm that the real example uses `unique_ptr` and already offers copy and move constructors/operators. Consider that the inner class has also a *clone* method that is used whenever I need to deeply copy it.

Comment: @skypjack plus a `type()` and `addressof()` for doing comparisons ;-) I use this paradigm of "inhertance is an implementation detail" a lot. It allows very clean logic to be presented in the algorithm that uses the object.

Comment: It offers `operator[]` and `operator=` through the base class to do comparisons. The type-erased inner classes currently wrap `std::array`s and `std::vector`s having custom allocators, so an array-like data structure in both the cases. The above mentioned operators are enough to compare those objects and abstract away from the actual types of the inner classes. Like it? Pretty clean a logic the one for comparison.