# When do Allocator::pointer and Allocator::value_type* differ?

Tags: c++, traits, allocator

I have a doubt regarding a question, in particular about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36032770/4987285) answer.
There is a part that *is left as an exercise for the reader* (it is not a problem for itself), in particular Jonathan Wakely (the author of the answer) said that:

> This code asserts that Allocator::pointer is Allocator::value_type*

That is expressed in code as:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename AT::pointer, typename AT::value_type*>::value, "Allocator doesn't use fancy pointers");
```

At the time, I got the answer as is and that's all.
When I was reading it again after a while, I found myself asking aloud: *fancy pointers?*
From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) (documentation of `allocator_traits`), `pointer` is defined as:

> Alloc::pointer if present, otherwise value_type*

The question thus arose: what's a realistic case in which `Allocator::pointer` and `Allocator::value_type*` actually differ?

Comment: It would hurt me actually, but it makes sense... Even though I guess it should be illegal in almost all the countries of the world!! Is really that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for an allocator are laid out in [[allocator.requirements]](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements). For an allocator class `X` for type `T`, the relevant requirements that I see are:

- `X::pointer` is convertible to `X::const_pointer`
- `*p` has type `T&`, where `p` is of type `X::pointer`
- `*q` has type `T const&` where `q` is of type `X::const_pointer`
- `p->m` has type `T::m` (conditioned on `(*p).m` being well-defined)
- `q->m` has type `T::m` (conditioned on `(*q).m` being well-defined)

All of those requirements are satisfed by `pointer` being `shared_ptr<T>`. In that case, `pointer` would definitely not be the same as `value_type*` (which would be `T*`).

Comment: Never thought about that, but it makes perfectly sense. Just for the sake of curiosity, have you ever used such an allocator? I've never seen something like that.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to mind is something that might have been realistic when the `allocator` spec was written.

A very long time ago, there were different types of pointers in the [Intel Segmented Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model): [*near*, *far*, and *huge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model), displaying speed/size tradeoffs.

Nowadays, with the current virtual memory architecture, they don't have any real use, anymore. In the old setting, though, conceptually an allocator could `typedef`:

```
 typdef T *huge pointer;
```

and it would carry more information than just `T *`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, you suggest it to be something that comes from another era of the computer science and that does not make much sense anymore nowadays, do you? Interesting, actually I cannot think at any use in a real scenario, but I'm not such a seasoned developer, so...

Answer (score 1):

Think of an allocator, that would create pointer-like objects, like smart pointers, or something similar, i.e. a structure with pointer and reference counter. As long as it serves it's purposes, the "non-standard" pointer structure can be used in most STL templates, also as a type returned by a specialized allocator.

As a realistic example, you can imagine an allocator that creates objects of type `std::shared_ptr`. The proper typedef would then look like `typedef std::shared_ptr<T> pointer;`, which would be vastly different from `T*`.